# How to format a date/time being returned from database to only show the time segment

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a cascading dropdownlist that is populated using a jQuery script.   Each Item in the list I want to display a code and a start time.  Something like:

C123 (7:30 am) 
  D345 (9:00 am)

I am having trouble working out how to format the date/time to show only the time in the list.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Shift").prop("disabled", true);
            //Dropdownlist Selectedchange event
            $("#StationList").change(function () {
                $("#Shift").empty();
                if ($("#StationList").val() != "Select a Station") {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '@Url.Action("GetShiftsByStation")', // we are calling json method
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: { selectedValue: $("#StationList").val() },
                        // here we are get value of selected Station and passing same value as input to json method GetShifts.
                        success: function (shiftList) {
                            // states contains the JSON formatted list
                            // of shifts passed from the controller
                            $("#Shift").append('<option value="' + null + '">' + "Please select a shift" + '</option>');

                            $.each(shiftList, function (i, shift) {
                                $("#Shift").append('<option value="' + shift.Value + '">' + shift.Text +  '</option>');
                                // here we are adding option for shifts
                                $("#Shift").prop("disabled", false);
                            });
                        },
                        error: function (ex) {
                            alert('Failed to retrieve shifts.' + ex);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    $("#Shift").empty();
                    $("#Shift").prop("disabled", true);
                }
            })
        });
</script>
```

The JQuery calls GetShiftsByStation in the **controller**

```
public JsonResult GetShiftsByStation(string selectedValue)
    {
        //Created object of service class which holds the method that queries database.
        DataAccess DataAccessService = new DataAccess();

        //Created a list of string to hold shifts from Database.
        List<SelectListItem> shiftList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        //Populating the list by calling GetShiftsByStationId method of service class.
        shiftList = DataAccessService.GetShiftsByStationId(Convert.ToInt32(selectedValue));
        //Returning the list using jSon.
        return Json(new SelectList(shiftList, "Value", "Text"));
    }
```

which calls GetShiftsByStationId(int stationId) to query the database and return a list of shifts for each location.

**Method**

```
//Gets the shift list based on StationId which is foreign key in Shifts table.
 public List<SelectListItem> GetShiftsByStationId(int stationId)
 {
     //Created DataContext to query DB.
     using (DataManager db = new DataManager())
     {
         //returns all the records from table based on StationId in list format.
         return db.Shifts.Where(query => query.StationId == stationId).Select(s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.ShiftId.ToString(), Text = s.Code + " (" + s.Start + ")" }).ToList();
     }
 }
```

So where and how am I best to format the date/time that is returned from the database?

I tried to use *s.Start.ToString("t")* but that didn't work because of course .ToString("t") is not supported in the LINQ query.

Comment: which version of entity framework are you using?

Comment: If you materialize you query - `db.Shifts.Where(...).ToList().Select(..)` you can use `string.Format` methods. But in anycase you should be returning a collection of anonymous objects, not a `SelectList` (the client has no knowledge of what a C# `SelectList` is) so your code is unnecessary extra overhead (you create a `SelectList` twice) and your sending back more data than is necessary

Comment: Using Entity Framework 6

Answer (score 0):

use this instead of `s.Start`

```
DbFunctions.CreateTime(s.Start.Hour, s.Start.Minute, s.Start.Second)
```

If you are not using EF6 use `EntityFunctions` instead of `DbFunctions`